# What could be the UML symbol of a Smart Watch?

Tags: uml, use-case

I am developing a prototype and so making UML Diagrams, for my USE CASE, I need to show the data being sent and received from a **smart watch**, I was wondering if there is a standard symbol for it or I should just draw one myself?

I have been using the attached.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

UML gives you the freedom to attach any shape to a stereotype. You can show it pure or as adornment in a corner of the rectangular element representation.

There is no standard other than rectangles (most UML elements), ovals (Use Cases), stickmen (Actors), rounded rects (Activities, Actions) and circles (mostly for state elements). (If there are more, they are quite uncommon and slipped my mind.)

For your watch you can take whatever you want. This one looks okay (although to me it looks more like a satellite).

Comment: Thank you for your feedback, I was convinced that there is no specific symbolic culture, but still its better to ask and be 100% sure.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not, UML is not that much specific, "portable computing device" is as specific as you'll get. So [pick something here](https://www.google.com/search?q=smartwatch%20icon&tbm=isch)

Comment: Thank you. I will drw something similar myself, because I do not want to copy image from internet, but the link is of course helpful.